How do you fake a lamp light in Eevee after Blender 4.2 update?
Before the 4.2 update, I could simply place a point light or spotlight inside the lamp model and increase the 'clip start' value to make it appear as though the light was emitting from inside the lamp. However, with the 'clip start' option now removed, I have no idea how to achieve the same effect. Does anyone know how you can fake a lamp light in Eevee in Blender 4.2?
